# Prevent termination of Word Application when user closes last document

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ms-word, office-interop

I have a simple Win Forms application that consists of a `Button` control, an `OpenFileDialog` component and a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` object:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WordInterop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // From Form1.Designer.cs:
        //Button openButton;
        //FileOpenDialog openFileDialog;

        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application _wordApp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            _wordApp.Quit();
            base.OnClosed(e);
        }

        private void _openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) {

                 // Throws COMException if Word app is not longer running
                _wordApp.Documents.Open(openFileDialog.FileName);

                _wordApp.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the `Open` button, they can selected a Word document via the `OpenFileDialog`. The filename of the selected document is used to open the Word Document using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` object.

It appears that the Word application is terminated when the user closes the last document: If the user clicks the `Open` button, selects a document, closes the document, clicks the `Open` button and selects a document a second time, a `COMException` occurs with the message *The RPC server is unavailable*. If there is at least one document open, the user can open documents without a `COMException` occurring.

Is there a way I can prevent Word application from terminating when the user closes the last document?

I tried creating a hidden blank document by changing the `Form1` constructor to the following:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    _wordApp.Documents.Add(Visible: false);
}
```

However the blank document becomes visible when the user opens a document meaning it is still possible for user terminate the Word application.

Comment: Why don't you just add the line `_wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();` to `_openButton_Click`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application() on the button click.

```
  private void _openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) {

            _wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            _wordApp.Documents.Open(openFileDialog.FileName);
            _wordApp.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is much slower then opening it earlier, show it if needed and hide it otherwise.